# Prove that $\frac{5}{1 \cdot 2 \cdot 3} + \frac{7}{3 \cdot 4 \cdot 5} + \frac{9}{5 \cdot 6 \cdot 7} + \cdots{} = -1 + 3 \log 2$

Tags: sequences-and-series

This is question of 12 class basic mathematics of Nepal.
$$
\frac{5}{1 \cdot 2 \cdot 3} + \frac{7}{3 \cdot 4 \cdot 5} + \frac{9}{5 \cdot 6 \cdot 7} + \cdots{} = -1 + 3 \log 2
$$
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/AP2JI.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  You'll get a lot more help, and fewer votes to close, if you show that you have made a real effort to solve the problem yourself.  What are your thoughts?  What have you tried?  How far did you get?  Where are you stuck?  This question is likely to be closed if you don't add more context.  Please respond by **editing the question body.**  Many people browsing questions will vote to close without reading the comments.  Also, please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: So you want to prove

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{2k+3}{(2k-1)2k(2k+1)} =3 \ln 2 -1 (= \ln \frac 8e).$$

Comment: Note $\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty\dfrac1{2k(2k-1)}=\ln2$

Comment: Partial Fractions gives $\frac{2k+3}{(2k-1)(2k)(2k+1)}=\frac2{2k-1}-\frac3{2k}+\frac1{2k+1}$

Answer (score 1):

Uing partial fractions decomposition
$$ a_k=\frac{2k+3}{(2k-1)(2k)(2k+1)}=\frac{2}{2 k-1}+\frac{1}{2 k+1}-\frac{3}{2 k}$$ So, using generalized harmonic numbers
$$S_n=\sum_{k=1}^n a_k=\left(H_{n-\frac{1}{2}}+2\log (2)\right)+\left(\frac{1}{2}H_{n+\frac{1}{2}}+\log (2)-1\right)-\left(\frac{3 }{2}H_n\right)$$

Now, using the asymptotics
$$H_p=\gamma +\log \left({p}\right)+\frac{1}{2 p}-\frac{1}{12
   p^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{p^3}\right)$$ apply it three times and continue with Taylor expansion to get
$$S_n=(3\log (2)-1)-\frac{1}{4 n}-\frac{1}{16n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)$$
which shows the limit and hos it is approached.

Computing $S_{10}=\frac{27260869}{25865840}=1.05393$ while the above truncated series gives $3\log (2)-\frac{1641}{1600}=1.05382$.

Answer (score 1):

$\begin{array}\\
S
&=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{2k+3}{(2k-1)2k(2k+1)}\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{2k+1+2}{(2k-1)2k(2k+1)}\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{2k+1}{(2k-1)2k(2k+1)}+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{2}{(2k-1)2k(2k+1)}\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(2k-1)2k}+2\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(2k-1)2k(2k+1)}\\
&=\ln(2)+2\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(2k-1)2k(2k+1)}\\
&=\ln(2)+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (\dfrac1{(2k-1)2k}-\dfrac1{(2k+1)2k})
\qquad\text{(see (*) below)}\\
&=\ln(2)+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \dfrac1{(2k-1)2k}-\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \dfrac1{(2k+1)2k}\\
&=2\ln(2)-\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \dfrac1{(2k+1)2k}\\
&=2\ln(2)-\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (\dfrac1{2k}-\dfrac1{2k+1})\\
&=2\ln(2)-S_1\\
S_1(m)
&=\sum_{k=1}^{m} (\dfrac1{2k}-\dfrac1{2k+1})\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^{m} \dfrac1{2k}-\sum_{k=1}^{m} \dfrac1{2k+1}\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^{m} \dfrac1{2k}-\sum_{k=2}^{m+1} \dfrac1{2k-1}\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^{m} \dfrac1{2k}-\sum_{k=1}^{m+1} \dfrac1{2k-1}+1\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^{m} \dfrac1{2k}-\sum_{k=1}^{m} \dfrac1{2k-1}+1-\dfrac1{2m+1}\\
&=1-\dfrac1{2m+1}+\sum_{k=1}^{m} \dfrac1{2k}-\sum_{k=1}^{m} \dfrac1{2k-1}\\
&=1-\dfrac1{2m+1}-\sum_{k=1}^{m} (\dfrac1{2k-1}-\dfrac1{2k})\\
&=1-\dfrac1{2m+1}-\sum_{k=1}^{m} \dfrac1{(2k-1)2k}\\
&\to 1-\ln(2)\\
\text{so}\\
S
&=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{2k+3}{(2k-1)2k(2k+1)}\\
&=3\ln(2)-1\\
\end{array}
$

(*)

$\dfrac1{(x-1)x}-\dfrac1{(x+1)x}
=\dfrac{(x+1)-(x-1)}{(x-1)x(x+1)}
=\dfrac{2}{(x-1)x(x+1)}
$

so
$\frac{2}{(2k-1)2k(2k+1)}
=\dfrac1{(2k-1)2k}-\dfrac1{(2k+1)2k}
$

Comment: Is there an error in the second line?

Comment: Yes. Nice catch. Upvoted. I forgot to edit out the 2K + 1 after I did the copy and paste. Fortunately, I had already mentally done that so it did not affect anything else.